# How to group similar items using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using automapper. And trying to do this map

```
public class Source
{
    public string UserName {get;set;}
    public string AppName {get;set;}
    public string Role {get;set;}
    public string Action {get;set;}
}

public class Destination
{
    public List<string> UserNames {get;set;}
    public string AppName {get;set;}
    public string Role {get;set;}
    public List<string> Actions {get;set;}
}
```

The idea is to combine the items with similar properties: AppName , Role.

Example:

List source =

1. {UserName = "John"; AppName = "MyApplication"; Role = "Admin"; Action = "Add" };
2. {UserName = "Elis"; AppName = "MyApplication"; Role = "Admin"; Action = "Edit" };

I want map to this :

List destination=

1. {UserNames = ["John", "Elis"]; AppName = "MyApplication"; Role = "Admin"; Action = ["Add", "Edit"] };

How can I do this. I need to map from sourse to destination and backwards.

Comment: This may require a [custom type converter](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html).

Comment: Would be less effort to just use a groupby and projection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this isn't automapper, but to give an easy alternative

> Note : This is assuming you want to actually group by `Role` and `AppName`

```
var destinations = list.GroupBy(x => new {x.AppName,x.Role})
                        .Select(x => new Destination
                            {
                                AppName = x.Key.AppName,
                                Role = x.Key.Role,
                                UserNames = x.Select(y => y.UserName).ToList(),
                                Actions = x.Select(y => y.Action).ToList()
                            })
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this is the most suitable solution.